# SVD and $\min ||A - B||$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

I have matrix $A$ and its SVD:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
11 & 14 & -4 \\
-8 & -2 & 7
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
405 & 0 \\
0 & 45
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{2}{27\sqrt{5}} & -\frac{2}{27\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{27\sqrt{5}} \\
-\frac{1}{9\sqrt{5}} & \frac{2}{9\sqrt{5}} & \frac{2}{9\sqrt{5}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I am asked to find B of rank 1 for which $||A - B||$ is minimal, where $||\cdot||$ is Frobenius norm.
Am i right, that 
$$
B =
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
405
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{2}{27\sqrt{5}} & -\frac{2}{27\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{27\sqrt{5}} \\
\end{pmatrix}?
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes -- this is a simple application of the [Eckart-Young](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Basic_low-rank_approximation_problem) theorem.